# End of tenancy and COVID notice period

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, landlord, covid-19

I'm in England, UK. I own a flat which I rent out, and live elsewhere with my girlfriend. We broke up and I need to go back to my flat. Under COVID law, I need to give 6 months' notice to my tenants, but their contract is coming to an end in 2 months' time.

Can I just not renew their contract and go back to my place in 2 months or do I still need to give them 6 months' notice?

Comment: The rules may vary so which part of the UK are you in? England, Wales, Scotland or Northern Ireland?

Comment: England, sorry (now added to the question).

Comment: Does this apply if you want to move in yourself as well?

Comment: Yeah I don't know and it doesn't seem clear from the government website

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Can I just not renew their contract and go back to my place in 2 months or do I still need to give them 6 months' notice?**

**Short answer**:

6 months' notice

**Long answer**:

I'm assuming this is a fixed-term Assured Shorthold Tenancy.

Unless a landlord is going down the Section 8 route where the tenant has broken the tenancy agreement, they will need to serve a "Section 21 Notice" under the [Housing Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/21?timeline=false) requesting the tenant to leave a property.

The Act has been amended to extend this notice period to 6 months, and any fixed-term tenancy that ends during that period will roll over to a periodic tenancy until the end of the notice period.

This is the relevant extract from the [government's website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/covid-19-and-renting-guidance-for-landlords-tenants-and-local-authorities/technical-guidance-on-eviction-notices):

> **Section 21 notices requiring possession of a property under an assured shorthold tenancy**
>
> Landlords can only use a Section 21 notice to ask their tenants to leave their property:
>
> - If the notice expires at or after the end of the fixed term.
> - During a tenancy with no fixed end date - known as a ‘periodic’ tenancy.
> - From 29 August 2020, a Section 21 notice must give tenants at least 6 months’ notice of the fact that the landlord requires possession.

[This](https://www.gov.uk/evicting-tenants/section-21-and-section-8-notices) give some more detail about s.21 Notices.

Answer (score 1):

> their contract is coming to an end in 2 months' time.

No, it isn't (assuming it's an assured shorthold tenancy). It sounds like the *fixed term* part of the tenancy is coming to an end in 2 months' time. If no-one does anything, the tenancy will automatically become a statutory periodic tenancy (often called a "rolling" tenancy) after that.

But the tenancy still exists, and as Rock Ape's answer states, you still need to issue a valid notice (probably a section 21 notice unless the tenants have stopped paying rent, etc) if you'd like the tenants to leave.

You are free to *ask* your tenants to leave (perhaps with a financial incentive), but they are free to refuse.