# What date can I issue a section 21 notice of eviction

Tags: united-kingdom, landlord, eviction

I am looking to issue a notice of eviction ([section 21](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/50/section/21?timeline=false) of the Housing Act 1988) to my tenants.

The contract has a break clause that states:

"Notwithstanding Schedule 3, this agreement may be ended by either party on or after 27th October 2021, the 18th month of the tenancy, providing sufficient written notice is served on the other party. This notice must be a minimum of two month’s written notice by the Tenant, and minimum two month’s written notice by the Landlord."

Can the notice be issued prior to this date to be actioned on 27/10/21, or does the notice have to  be issued no earlier than this date?

Currently the UK has additional restrictions extending notice periods to 4 months rather than 2 months (for notices given on or after 01/06/21).

Comment: Related post: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/62082/end-of-tenancy-and-covid-notice-period/62086?r=SearchResults#62086

Comment: @RockApe please don’t answer in comments.